# How to use :not selector with current selector parent (&) in less

Tags: html, less

I am facing an issue while applying :not selector along with & in less. Without :not the less is working fine. Can anyone please see what is the issue with it..

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p class="orange">Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

**LESS:**

```
div {
    p {
        color: #c0c0c0;
        &.orange {
            //color: #ff6600; //This works
        }
        &:nth-child(1), :not(&.orange) { //But with :not, it isn't working...
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kunjsharma/adu69t1s/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` has to go at the beginning of the selector.

```
&:nth-child(1), 
&:not(.orange)
```

Comment: Well, in Less it [does not have to](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order), though in this particular case it's what the op needs.

Comment: IMO it's more useful to think of the `&` symbol as a reference to the parent selector.